# Uikit Sticky oversized content

Tags: javascript, html, uikit, sticky, getuikit

Hello
I am using UIKIT's sticky component on the image which needs sticky right away when scrolling starts.
It works fine but if the image is oversized to the viewport (like in laptops), so the sticky position does not work as long as the bottom of the photo is inside the viewport.
is there a way to immediately sticky the image when i scroll even though it is oversized to the viewport?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sticky</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- UIkit CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.10/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

    <!-- UIkit JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.10/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.13.10/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div uk-sticky="sel-target: .uk-navbar-container; cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky; bottom: #transparent-sticky-navbar">
        <nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-navbar-transparent uk-background-primary uk-light" uk-navbar
            style="position: relative; z-index: 9999980;">
            <div class="uk-navbar-center">
                <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">NAVBAR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <div id="test" class="uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-1-2 uk-text-center" uk-grid>

        <div>
            <div class="uk-background-muted" uk-sticky="bottom: true; offset:80" style="z-index: 980;">
                <div>
                    <img data-src="http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/1200x1400.png?text=IMAGE" width="1200" height="1400"
                        loading="lazy" src="http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/1200x1400.png?text=IMAGE">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-background-muted uk-padding uk-dark">
            <article class="uk-article uk-text-left">

                <h1 class="uk-article-title"><a class="uk-link-reset" href="">Heading</a></h1>

                <p class="uk-article-meta">Written by <a href="#">Super User</a> on 12 April 2012. Posted in
                    <a href="#">Blog</a></p>

                <p class="uk-text-lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
                    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                    est laborum.</p>


                    <div class="uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto" uk-grid>
                        <div>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-text" href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-text" href="#">5 Comments</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-container uk-container-expand uk-height uk-background-secondary">
        <div>
            <div class="uk-height-large uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle">
                Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```